# Newbie Question about Web Content Display and Templates

Tags: java, liferay, portal, intranet

Im using Liferay Portal v5.2.3 Community Edition. I have the following two questions which i hope someone would be kind enough to answer.

1.) I want to add some content to the About Us Page of my intranet portal. I added Web Content Display portlet, and maximized the screen after adding content. But accessing the portal, it always appears minimized.
Any way to solve this issue ?

2.) When i try to add a template after creating a structure, i have to select the script file to be used. I found some vm files for 7Cogs portal,but couldnt find any for the organization i created . Where are these vm or css files located and which one to use ?

Please Help.
Thank You.

Comment: You might want to post from a registered account (or register with the one that you're currently using, provided you still got the cookie) so you'll be able to rephrase your question to give more information. I guess this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919703) is from you too, right?

Answer (score 0):

For 1) There's no need to "maximize" anything if that's the only thing you have on a page. Just choose the single-column layout and place your Web Content in this single column that covers the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) you'll have to add the templates yourself. Every template belongs to a structure, so if you create your own structure, you also need to create templates that can display this structure.

You create templates in the same place you create structures: Go to the Control Panel. In the "Web Content" section you find tabs for structures and templates. When you create a template you need to specify a matching structure there. Once you've done that you can choose that template in your web content