# Someone please help me with this Web Content Display problem in Liferay..im stuck !

Tags: java, liferay, portal

Any way to make the web content appear maximized by default instead of minimized ?.Im using Liferay v5.2.3 Community Edition.

Please Help.
Thank You

Comment: please elaborate a bit - Web Content is not "minimized" by default... Are you choosing the correct portlet to display web content?

Comment: See the answer to your (?) other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918446

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're trying to do, you'd like a menu item to display static HTML... If this is in fact what you want to do, then you can set the page 'type' under "manage pages" to 'article' and set the article id as well.  This will show the article content (HTML) under that page (maximized).  If it's an external HTML page you can do embedded as the page type I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is to maximise web content over the whole page? rather than having two columns?

If i'm right then all you have to do is make the page have one column. As administrator go to:

Manage --> Page Layout --> One Column --> Save